# Not getting image in Image Control by Url in asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Hello Friends i am storing an image via URL in database but when i retrieve it on Image Control of asp.net it doesn't show the image please help

```
Profile.aspx.cs

con.Open();
                    string str = "SELECT * FROM [aspdotnetpractice].[dbo].[Users]  where Username ='" + lblHowdy.Text + "'";
                    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(str, con);
                    SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
                    if (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Image1.ImageUrl = Server.MapPath(reader[8].ToString());
                        Label1.Text = reader[1].ToString();
                        Label2.Text = reader[2].ToString();
                        Label3.Text = reader[3].ToString();
                        Label4.Text = reader[6].ToString();
                        Label5.Text = reader[4].ToString();
                        reader.Close();
                        con.Close();
                    }
```

Comment: First check what `Server.MapPath(reader[8].ToString())` outputs. Second, check that the image exists on that url.

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Write one example of `reader[8].ToString()` - image url

Comment: image is there in images folder and image path is stored in database , i am retrueving the path here reader[8].ToString() and giving it to Image Control

Comment: UserId Fullname Gender DOB Username Password Email FileName FilePath
1 asas    Male   7/28/2014 adeebhat99  adeebhat@live.co.uk                                                                      2.png                                              images/2.png

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you save path value like "ImageFiles/test.jpg" or filename only like "test.jpg". Dont save to path field a complete local path like "c:\…\test.jpg". In imageurl you should use virtual path instead physical path.

The Server.MapPath returns a file name. On the other hand, Image.ResolveUrl expects a valid url.

You'd rather want something like

```
 Image1.ImageUrl = Page.ResolveUrl("~/ImageFiles/") + fi.Name; // You just need to pass name or something similar.
```